# display php / mysql column output as rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below syntax that is used to display a MySQL query in PHP:

```
 function get_dayssincecapture($db)  
  {    
    $result = $db->query("SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive)as days,count(loadnumber) as loads from v2loads where  adminstatus='captured' group by DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) "); 
    return $result; 
  } 
  $dayssincecapture = get_dayssincecapture($db);
```

Display Syntax:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <? while($row = $dayssincecapture->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <td><? echo $row['days']; ?><br><? echo $row['loads']; ?></td>
    <? } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this produces the below screen output

[image]

How do I alter by table syntax in order to get the days field as a row heading and the load field as the second row of my table?

so what I want will be:

[image]

Thanks as always,

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution or php?

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet, comfortable with either. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
<?php
$dayssincecapture = get_dayssincecapture($db); 
$data = array('days' => array(), 'loads' => array());

while($row = $dayssincecapture->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data['days'][]  = $row['days'];
    $data['loads'][] = $row['loads'];
}
?>

<table style="border: 1px solid #000">
    <tr>
        <td>Days</td>
        <?php foreach ( $data['days'] as $day ) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $day; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Loads</td>
        <?php foreach ( $data['loads'] as $load ) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $load; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome @hsz, appreciate the prompt reply. awesome syntax, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to perform this type of transformation in MySQL, then you will be *pivoting* the data. MySQL does not have a pivot function but you can replicate this using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 1 then loadnumber end) as Day_1,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 2 then loadnumber end) as Day_2,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 3 then loadnumber end) as Day_3,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 4 then loadnumber end) as Day_4,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 5 then loadnumber end) as Day_5,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 6 then loadnumber end) as Day_6,
  count(case when DATEDIFF(now(), sarrive) = 7 then loadnumber end) as Day_7
from v2loads
where adminstatus='captured'
```

You can also write this code inside of a prepared statement to create this dynamically since the values will be unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<?php

while($row = $dayssincecapture->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $days_row .= "<td>" . $row['days'] . "</td>";
    $loads_row .= "<td>" . $row['loads'] . "</td>";
}

?>
<table> 

  <tr>
    <td>Days</td>
    <?php echo $days_row; ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Loads</td>
    <?php echo $loads_row; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```